# How to close camera (OpenCv Beaglebone)

Tags: c++, opencv, camera, beagleboard

Good Day,

I am trying to figure out how to close the camera on a beaglebone in openCV. I have tried numerous commands such as release(&camera) but none exist and the camera continues to stay on when I don't want it to.

```
VideoCapture capture(0);
capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,320);
capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,240);
if(!capture.isOpened()){
     cout << "Failed to connect to the camera." << endl;
}
Mat frame, edges, cont;

while(1){
    cout<<sending<<endl;
    if(sending){
        for(int i=0; i<frames; i++){
            capture >> frame;
            if(frame.empty()){
            cout << "Failed to capture an image" << endl;
            return 0;
            }
            cvtColor(frame, edges, CV_BGR2GRAY);
```

Code is something like this, at the end of the for loop, I want to close the camera, but of course it still stays open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The camera will be deinitialized automatically in VideoCapture destructor.

Check this example from opencv docu:

```
int main(int, char**)
{
    VideoCapture cap(0); // open the default camera
    if(!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
        return -1;

    Mat edges;
    namedWindow("edges",1);
    for(;;)
    {
        Mat frame;
        cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera
        cvtColor(frame, edges, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        GaussianBlur(edges, edges, Size(7,7), 1.5, 1.5);
        Canny(edges, edges, 0, 30, 3);
        imshow("edges", edges);
        if(waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
    }
    // the camera will be deinitialized automatically in VideoCapture destructor
    return 0;
}
```

Also

> cvQueryFrame
>
> Grabs and returns a frame from camera or file
>
> IplImage* cvQueryFrame( CvCapture* capture );
>
> capture video capturing structure.
>
> The function cvQueryFrame grabs a frame from camera or video file, decompresses and  > returns it. This function is just a combination of cvGrabFrame and cvRetrieveFrame in one > call. **The returned image should not be released or modified by user.**

Also check: http://derekmolloy.ie/beaglebone/beaglebone-video-capture-and-image-processing-on-embedded-linux-using-opencv/

I hope this works for you. Best of luck.

Comment: I just had to do camera.release(). But thx for the detailed reply!